# Запуск функции с параметром

Tags: c, параметры

Доброго дня.

Имеется два файла:
**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FillingABC(a, b, c);
    FillingABC();   
    return 0;

}
```

И **Functions.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int n;
int a[20], b[20], c[20]; // В задании сказано, что они не больше 20
int x[20], y[20]; // Заодно выделим и для x, y

void FillingABC () {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {  //Заполняем массив а случайными числами от 1 до 50
        int number = 0 + rand() %50;
        a[i] = number;
        printf("%d ", a[i]); //Выводим массив а
    }
    printf("\n");
     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {  //Заполняем массив b случайными числами от 1 до 50
        int number = 0 + rand() %50;
        b[i] = number;
        printf("%d ", b[i]); //Выводим массив b
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++ ) {  //Заполняем массив c случайными числами от 1 до 50
        int number = 0 + rand() %50;
        c[i] = number;
        printf("%d ", c[i]); //Выводим массив c
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
```

Собственно, хочется избавиться от двух лишних for-ов, а в main.c просто вызывать функцию FillingABC для массивов a, b и с.
Как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо просто передавать массив в функцию как аргумент. И создавать их в main.c. Для каждого массива вызывать функцию отдельно. То есть:

```
void Fill (int* ar, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        int number = rand() % 50;
        ar[i] = number;
        printf("%d ", ar[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = 20;
    int a[n], b[n], c[n];
    Fill(a, n);
    Fill(b, n);
    Fill(c, n);
    return 0;
}
```

В общем, чтобы делать код более коротким, понятным и универсальным, следует выносить переменные, числа в аргументы и константы.

Comment: Вы бы добавили пример кода.